# LINQ Query not working for Right Outer Join

Tags: sql, .net, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion, linqer

I have a SQL Query which I want to convert to LINQ. I am using C#. I tried both LINQPad and Linqer. Linqer does not do a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. LINQPad does not do any conversion at all.

Can it be done via nested joins or like?

```sql
SELECT dbo.tblPatientMaster.ptM_Name 
FROM dbo.tblClinicalInformation 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblPatientDiagnosis 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblDiagnosisInformation ON 
        dbo.tblPatientDiagnosis.ptD_tgIId = dbo.tblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_Id 
ON dbo.tblClinicalInformation.tcI_Id = dbo.tblDiagnosisInformation.tgI_tcIId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPatientInformation ON 
    dbo.tblPatientDiagnosis.ptD_ptIId = dbo.tblPatientInformation.ptI_Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblDepartmentMaster 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblDoctorMaster ON 
        dbo.tblDepartmentMaster.deptM_Id = dbo.tblDoctorMaster.dcM_deptMId 
ON dbo.tblPatientInformation.ptI_dcMId = dbo.tblDoctorMaster.dcM_Id 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblPatientMaster ON 
    dbo.tblPatientInformation.ptI_Id = dbo.tblPatientMaster.ptM_Id
```

Comment: have you considered using a Stored prosedure? the Linq code for this would be really ugly and unmaintainable.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the valuable comment. I shall go for better alternative then...

Comment: If you're using repositories surely a Stored Procedure is a step in the wrong direction? The LINQ code need not be too "ugly" and I would dispute the maintainability of Stored Procs over LINQ!

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using? Eg LINQ-2-SQL, NHibernate, EF, etc...?

Comment: Instead of Joins you should consider EF & its navigation properties, which will give you better query & readability

Comment: Please never just drop SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible.

Comment: @user2582424 I agree with you in generel. *But* in my opinion writing Linq querys with any kind of joins (other that inner join) is very combersome. In OP's case, I would prefer a Stored Prosedure - because it feels more *directly to the point* in its syntax. And that makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you ALL gr8 guys for helping me out. I did it through query.